# Received offer letter, accepted but haven’t received confirmation email

Tags: job-offer, new-job, job-change

I received an offer letter more than two weeks ago with start date November 30. I asked them that if it was possible to start next year. They told me that they were ok with that. I accepted the offer but I haven’t received from them neither a confirmation email or the updated offer letter with the new start date since November 19th. Last weekend I sent them an email trying to confirm with them if they received my answer to their offer. They haven’t replied yet…..

At this point, I’m starting to think that they ghosted me…. And the problem is that I was planning to quit my current job in less than two weeks….

Any recommendations in what to do?
Should I call HR?
Email the hiring manager?
Send another email?

Edit:
This [question asked](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018) is not the same as my case. In my case, I already received an offer letter. After that, the company went radio silent with me. By the way, It turned out that the email I sent went to their spam folder... They didn't ghost me... but yeah, I agree, I should've called them after some days of radio silence...

Comment: Call them on the phone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I properly follow-up with a hiring manager, to check on the status of a position?](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/6018/how-do-i-properly-follow-up-with-a-hiring-manager-to-check-on-the-status-of-a-p)

Comment: @gnat No, in my situation I already received the job offer...

Comment: It turned out that the email I sent went to their spam folder... They didn't ghost me... but yeah, I agree, I should've called them after some days of radio silence....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> *Should I call HR?*

Long overdue. Call them **now**.

To elaborate, you have waited just too long. It's almost two weeks. Verbal communication is not of much worth, unless the same is communicated in writing. I don't know why you'd accept the old offer (with previous start date), but anyways, you **must** have an updated copy of the offer letter, or an official addendum mentioning the extension of the joining date, and have that one accepted and receipt acknowledged. Since the previous offer is to be updated, accepting that or acknowledging that is of no use, don't bank on that acceptance from your side.

Clearly, your emails are not cutting it through, if you have a contact number, call them up and enquire about the process. It may just be that due to the extended joining date in next year, there's a delay in sending the revised version; it might have been fell through crack, or you might have been ghosted. You'll never know for sure unless you ask (and I mean, talk to someone who can answer your questions, not e-mails).

Answer (score 0):

HR are probably the least organised and efficient department of any company, and the recruitment team doubly so. It will be because someone has forgotten to tick a box or complete some form or other to get you your laptop or your login or whatever.

Call them on the phone immediately.

When I am waiting for recruiters and hiring managers to get back to me after a successful interview process, I generally call them every 2 days if they haven't called me first just for an update.

You're basically in now, you can be as annoying and persistent as you want, you can't lose the job over that.